# An integer $n$ is called "funfable" provided $5|(n-2)$ and integer $n$ is called "unfunfable" provided $5|(n-3)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

An integer $n$ is called "funfable" provided $5|(n-2)$ and integer $n$ is called "unfunfable" provided $5|(n-3)$
Let $x$ and $y$ be integers such that $x + y = 50$. Prove or disprove: $x$ is funfable if and only if $y$ is unfunfable.

I know this is always true but am having trouble proving why.

Comment: Hint: If $5|m$, then $5|m+5x$ for any integer $x$. Use this to take out or add multiples of $5$ to $x-2$ to get $y-3$ and vice versa.

Comment: The terminology is confusing as the prefix "un" generally denotes "not"  though here you mean something different.

Comment: @Jeff I've reworded your question into what I think is clearer language. Please let me know if I've changed the meaning

Comment: @Jam - that should go in an answer, not in the question. Don't make an edit that gives the impression of stronger understanding than originally shown.

Comment: @Joffan Yeah, fair point. I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is true :

$x$ is "funfable" $\iff$ $x\equiv 2\mod 5$ $\iff$ $y\equiv 3\mod 5$ $\iff$ $y$ is "unfunfable"

The middle equivalence follows immediately from $$x+y\equiv 0\mod 5$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ if funfable, then $5\mid (x-2)$, so $x-2=5d$ for some integer $d$.  Then $50 = x+y = (5d+2) +y$, so $y= 50-5d-2  = 45-5d+3 = 5(9-d)+3$.  Then $y-3 = 5(9-d)$, so $5\mid(y=3)$ and therefore $y$ is unfunfable.  The other direction is identical.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way of explaining **Peter's** answer, if you're not comfortable with modular arithmetic. If $5|(x-2)$ then the final digit of $x$ is either $2$ or $7$ since multiples of $5$ end in either $0$ or $5$. Then $x=10n+2$ or $10n+7$ for some integer, $n$. Then, since $y=50-x=48-10n$ or $43-10n$, the final digit of $y$ is either $8$ or $3$, which proves $5|(y-3)$.